# Im having trouble with a glowing object

Tags: texturing

Im trying to edit edit a texture to have a shiny color but I cant get it right.

I want it to look like the one on the right.
[image]

Here is the [image]
It doesnt have to look exactly like it just anything to get rid of that glow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.8. If you don't want any glow effect, don't enable it.

[image: glow]

Disable the `Bloom` here.

Now if you want to keep the white highlight on your model, this will be done with either the material, either by cranking up the main light's strength, either both.

This could be an example of material:

[image: example material]

Comment: Enabling glow effect? Where? Can you  upload a gif or a.blend so I can see?

Comment: Disable the bloom in the render tab, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Bloom = glow? Wow I should have known that. I guess I was too distracted trying to burn that 4-D cube. 3-D is enough dimensions.